# Changing a value in a session database with a button?

Tags: php, session-variables

First off I do want to state that I am using old code. I will replace it with MySQLi. I am really on a time crunch for this and I am stuck on one code. I am trying to change the sub field from default to yes when I hit submit.

```
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_id   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| username  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| password  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| email     | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| city      | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| state     | varchar(2)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| zip       | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| phone     | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| firstName | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| lastName  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| sub       | varchar(5)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| orderDate | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| endDate   | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |
```

This is connected to a lot of other webpages I am working on. I was able to get everything else to work just fine. I want to be able to type yes into a field and once I hit submit the sub field in my database will change from null to yes for the session user. I just have no idea how to update a session user. I have tried many different combos and it could be because I am using old code. This is not going to be live. I am just trying to wrap my head around this code and I will fix all the issues when I am no longer in a time crunch. Here is my .php page

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','user','password');
mysql_select_db('db');
session_start();
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
if(!$username){
    die("Please login");
}
else
{
$query="select *from users WHERE username='$username' ";
$run=mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run)){
$admin=$row['username'];
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>entrySubscription</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="Substyle.css">  
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" name="myForm" autocomplete="on">
<p><label>Please type yes &#40;required&#41; <input type="text" name="sub""/> </label></p>     
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit response" />
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear form" /> 
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i would expect to see an UPDATE query in there

Comment: So is your issue with creating php code to catch the posted `<form>` values, or on a mysql `UPDATE` query?

Comment: Updating the query. I was able to created a new row by accident. I am trying to figure out how to update the query.

Comment: Where is your `UPDATE` query attempt? You already have a `SELECT` using the `$username`(/`$_SESSION['username']`). So an `UPDATE` would be similar - `UPDATE users SET sub = 'yes' WHERE username='$username'`

Comment: Would this be with `$_POST['submit'])) { }?`. I am going to try a few things and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Yes, you would want to wrap the `UPDATE` query in a `$_POST['submit'])) { ... }` as you would only want to update on form submit. You could also use a `if($_POST['sub'] == 'yes')`, to prevent updating when the value is empty or `no`, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I have been trying to figure this out for hours. The update works.

Answer (score 1):

you could submit the form to itself the set what you need

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: I have tried this. I was able to create a new row with the sub field updated. Updating the sub field for the session user is what I am having difficulty with.